# Find an object within a list and replace its value

Tags: c#, linq, list, class

I have the following list and class:

```
List<MyClass> MyList

public class MyClass
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public bool checked { get; set; }
}
```

I also have the two variables:

```
int idToFind = 1234;
bool newcheckedvalue = true;
```

What I need to do is search the list and find the MyClass object where the id equals that value of `idToFind`. Once I have the object in the list, I then want to change the value of the checked property in the class to that of the `newcheckedvalue` value.

LINQ seems to be the solution to this problem, I just can't get the expression right. Can I do this in a single LINQ expression?

Comment: If the `id`s are unique across instances you could put them in a `Dictionary<int, MyClass>` instead then it would be as simple as `MyDictionary[idToFind].checked = newcheckedvalue;`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

LINQ is for querying collection, not for modification. You can find the object like:

```
var item = MyList.FirstOrDefault(r=> r.id == idtoFind && r.checked == newcheckedvalue);
```

To find the item based on the `ID` only you can do:

```
var item = MyList.FirstOrDefault(r=> r.id == idtoFind);
```

Later you can set/modify its property.

```
//Make sure to check against Null, as if item is not found FirstOrDefault will return null
item.checked = newcheckedvalue; //or any other value
```

Comment: `!= newcheckedvalue`, surely?  And then `item.checked = newcheckedvalue`.

Comment: Of course as usual, you might need to handle the default (null) case.  But yeah `.FirstOrDefault` is the way to go.

Comment: @CharlesMager, you made me thinking, I guess the OP wants to find records based on `id` only.

Answer (score 2):

Example (to be noted that `MyClass` type has to be a *class*, a reference type, in this example):

```
var found  = MyList.Where(ml=>ml.Id == 1234); 
foreach(var f in found)
    f.checked = newcheckedvalue;
```